# Cash check in France and have the money wired to the US

Tags: banking, check, stimulus

The title says it all. I received my stimulus check (some time ago).
As an expat, I have a US bank account open, so I would need to have some bank in France cash the check and then wire the money over my US bank account.

The problem is:

- Most (french) banks don't accept US checks
- When they do they will cash them in euros at whatever exchange rate they want (which usually is ridiculous, and they apply a fee on top of that)

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks.

Edit:
Why can't I just remote deposit?: My bank is Capital One, they won't allow me to deposit checks from outside the US (although it is online). Tried using a VPN, didn't help.

Perhaps someone know of a bank that allows to open an account remotely that allows to cash checks from outside the US online?

Comment: If you have a US bank account, why can't you do a remote deposit?

Comment: My bank is One Capital, they won't allow me to deposit from outside the US (although it is online). Tried using a VPN, didn't help. Perhaps I should clarify that in the post.

Comment: You can mail the check to your bank for deposit.

Comment: One Capital or Capital One? If Cap One does [this reference](https://www.capitalone.com/bank/mobile-check-deposit/) help?

Comment: @24601 Yes, Capital One. As I said, what they don't tell you, is that you have to be in the us for that to work.

Comment: [this quora commentary](https://qr.ae/pGxfYZ) suggests it is possible...

Comment: What is credit union? It's not a bank is it? I'll try another bank, perhaps other will in fact allow it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**You should be able to mail the check to your bank for deposit.**

I've done this a number of times, although admittedly never with a US bank (which are, shall we say, idiosyncratic.)

Write a letter telling them that you have enclosed a check for $N and to deposit it to account nnnn. Put it and the check in the mail. Address it to your bank. If you are feeling cautious sent it by registered mail.

Comment: Thanks. I'll email support first, just to confirm this is an option.